# Why does OpenURI return different HTML content from the original source?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri, open-uri, css-parsing

I'm trying to get style contents from HTML source using OpenUri and Nokogiri.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'css_parser'

url  = open('https://google.com')
html = Nokogiri::HTML(url)
css  = CssParser::Parser.new
css.add_block!(html.search('style#gstyle').text)
```

This returns `nil`, but the HTML of the Google page contains `id="gstyle"`. Here is an image of the output result:

[image]

1. Why is the Google HTML page, in this example, different from that which OpenUri returns?
2. How can I find this tag `style#gstyle`?
3. Why does Firebug see the correct HTML document and OpenUri does not?

Comment: In 3, how do you know that the firebug's page is the correct one and the open-uri's page is not?

Comment: Disregarding such asymmetry seen in 3, what is the difference between questions 1 and 3?

Comment: Don't trust browser-based tools to display HTML accurately. If you want to know what the page *really* looks like, go straight to the source using `curl` or `wget` or OpenURI and look at what comes back. Browsers are like puppies and try to please us by rendering something, even if it means changing the HTML. Anything using the browser's rendered HTML will be wrong at that point, including Firebug. And, BTW, you can use `nokogiri some_url` at the command-line if you want to see the true source also.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google renders its page differently for different clients, based on the agent string, and the agent string is the only clue the server has about what kind of client is accessing the page. `open-uri` by default declares itself to be "Ruby". If you are visiting with a clearly automated script, you will not get the same page as if you were visiting with a browser.

Try this:

```
url = open('https://google.com', "User-Agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36")
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot!

Comment: From past experience, in a previous life, we found that Google also seems to change rendering depending on a random whim and fancy which we interpreted to be an attempt to discourage scraping and spidering of their pages.

Comment: @theTinMan: That too. I probably should add that I was answering the literal question (why `open` != Firebug); I don't know if OP's use case is a one-time thing or they're going for scraping, but if the latter, you should not be using `open` on Google for scraping purposes, rather use Google API if you don't want to earn an IP ban.